# Query in RavenDB returns no element

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am trying to start to use RavenDB.

I have a database in RavenDb with address with Zipcode, latitude and longitude and other fields due address.

When I try to get this data using RavenDb,it always doesn't return any record. I tried to use in this two ways:

```
 var elements = session
   .Query<EnderecoComCepEGeo>()
   .ToList();
```

```
 var query =
   (from t in session.Query<EnderecoComCepEGeo>()
   select t).ToList();
```

In the both statemenst it does't returng any record.

Using Query the system responds as the database/document doesn't have any records. If I use first or single, it throw a exception "Sequence contains no element".

But if I use the load, it work's normaly

```
  var element = session.Load<EnderecoComCepEGeo>("Teste/0000000000002111528-A");
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database?  Do you have permission to read the database with the account you are using?  Check your connection string.  If data exists either you are connecting to the wrong database or there is a credential issue.

Comment: This 3 statements is using the same session. And only Load returns the values.

Comment: Add exception handler around statements that are failing and see what the trace stacks indicates.

Comment: @b3r3ch1t are the documents in the `EnderecoComCepEGeos` collection?
Can you share the metadata from one of those documents?